# Calculating time difference between consecutive rows does not work within graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I have a dataset with time-stamped GPS points. I would like to calculate the time difference in seconds between these rows.  I successfullymanaged to do so by running the piece of code below in the field calculator outside the graphical modeler. However, when I want to calculate the time difference with the field calculator **in** a graphical model, it does not work.. It only generates NULL values, except for row with id 0. I used the exact same code. Any ideas what the problem is?

```
CASE WHEN id=0 THEN 0
ELSE
second(age(attribute($currentfeature, 'datetime'), 
       attribute(get_feature_by_id('[layername]',$id-1), 'datetime')))
END
```

[image]

Comment: What is your output field type?

Comment: The output field type is Integer

Comment: What happens when you try `string`?